# Upload file s3 NestJs

Tags: file, amazon-s3, nestjs, aws-sdk

I try to upload image to s3 cloud(NestJs, aws-sdk), but get an error (on screen):
Error [XMLParserError]: Non-whitespace before first tag

Have anyone has the same and know how to fix?

```
const { originalname, buffer } = file;

const params = {
  Bucket: 'storage',
  Key: String(originalname),
  Body: buffer,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  ContentType: file.mimetype,
};

// params - {
//  Bucket: 'storage',
//  Key: 'aaa_nature.jpeg',
//  Body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 f0 00 f0 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 02 02 02 03 02 02 02 03 03 03 03 4 06 04 04 04 04 04 08 06 06 05 ... 112702 more bytes>,
//  ACL: 'public-read',
//  ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
// }

try {
  return await this.s3.putObject(params).promise();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image!